# How to access Dialog's view without creating additional class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, onitemclicklistener

Does anyone know which context (if that) would I need to use for a click listener in a RecyclerView adapter without having to create a new DialogFragment class? I will need to access and use the dialog's view in future. The **previously used code** is what I've used in the past for my RecyclerView adapter but it's now redundant when needing to use the custom view.

> Unresolved reference: 'layoutInflater'

**previously used code**

```
    holder.myButton.setOnClickListener {
        val builder = android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(holder.itemView.context)
        builder.setIconAttribute(R.attr.ivInfo)
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
        builder.setView(R.layout.custom_view)
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok){ dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

        val dialog: android.app.AlertDialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
```

**current code**

```
class MyRVAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.myButton.setOnClickListener {
            customView = holder.itemView.context.this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)

                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(holder.itemView.context)
                 builder.setIconAttribute(R.attr.imgNight)
                 builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
                 builder.setView(customView)
                 builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok){ dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }
                 builder.show()

                tabLayout = customView.findViewById(R.id.mTabLayout)
                viewPager = customView.findViewById(R.id.mViewPager)

                val adapter = TabbedDialogAdapter(childFragmentManager)
                adapter.addFragment("Tab A", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description A"))
                adapter.addFragment("Tab B", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description B"))
                adapter.addFragment("Tab C", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description C"))

                customView.mViewPager.adapter = adapter
                customView.mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(customView.mViewPager)
            }
        }
     }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_cv, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val myButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_A)!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use your Activity as context.

Comment: @RaymondArteaga Do you mean to use `getActivity` somewhere?

Comment: Setting listener in onBindViewHolder() is not a good idea.  You should set in creation of ViewHolder instead. In the constructor of ViewHolder or onCreateViewHolder(). There you will have `View` and you can use `view.context`

Comment: @underoid see my latest code edit for **current code**

Comment: Why are you creating `AlertDialog ` in `onBindViewHolder` or creating `adapter` object? `onBindViewHolder` serves as binder for `Views` and data. That means your dialog and adapter will be created as many times as your list size is

Comment: @Yupi I did follow a tutorial for this one. How can I access the button from `onCreateViewHolder`?

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad, I didn't pay attention this is inside `OnClickListener`, I thought you put that directly inside `onBindViewHolder`. That code right now should work if you just use this line `customView = View.inflate(holder.itemView.context, R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)`. But better practice is to set click listeners inside `ViewHolder` where you connected your button with `id`: `val myButton = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_A)!!`

Comment: @Yupi Ok so would I do something like `myButton.setOnClickListener{...}` or something else?

Comment: @MacaronLover Yes

Comment: @Yupi Using that code returns this error: `Expecting Member Declaration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you can use `View.inflate()`.

Change this line:

`customView = holder.itemView.context.this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)`

to this:

`customView = View.inflate(holder.itemView.context, R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)`

But you should set listeners on creation of ViewHolder instead. In the constructor of ViewHolder or `onCreateViewHolder()`.

Comment: Which one those is better or the most recommended? The `ViewHolder` constructor or `onCreateViewHolder()`?

Comment: I already created my button in a `viewHolder` class so how can that be accessed for `onCreateViewHolder()`?

Comment: You get the created `ViewHolder` object in `onCreateViewHolder()` and you have access to `itemView` only. So constructor is better.